# Sieve of Erathosthenes, represent multiples of numbers

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to determine prime numbers with the Sieve of Erathosthene, with an boolean array(every values start with false value)
Here are my problems:

- I can't represent the multiple of 2,3,5,7 to assign them the value "true" and have only my remaining prime numbers with the value of "false"
- How to get the int value of the prime numbers instead of their boolean value?

here's what I did
[image]

useful link
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: This is not the right way to implement SOE, check out this [link](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/08/use-the-sieve-of-eratosthenes-to-find-prime-numbers-in-c/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code makes outside the bounds indexes. The following code should work:

```
int n = 120;
        bool[] array = new bool[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (i != 1)
            {
                if (2 * i < n)
                    array[2 * i] = true;
                if (3 * i < n)
                    array[3 * i] = true;
                if (5 * i < n)
                    array[5 * i] = true;
                if (7 * i < n)
                    array[7 * i] = true;
            }

            if (array[i] == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi Hadi, thanks I saw where I made mistakes, about the bounds that means, the value of the multiple exceeded the length of the array right? Moreover I removed the first if statement and put inside the for loop i=2 because of zero and one